# What is the best way to store this information?

Tags: php, mysql

I have database with a user table like so:

```
table users:
user_id (int)
user_name (varchar)
etc..
```

This user will be able to fill in a couple of requirements like:

- Minimal Salary (int)
- Has driver's license (bool)
- My other demands (text)

The return value of the `User->get(user_id);` must be something like this:

```
user_id: 1,
user_name: 'John Doe',
user_requirements: {
    minimal_salary: 2000,
    drivers_license: true,
    demands: 'These are my demands..'
}
```

What will be the best way to store this in a Database?

I know you can use a 1 on 1 relation. (it will cost a join or seperate query)
You can store it all in 1 table. (it will cost some tweaking in de code)
You can normalize this in to many to many relation with a type (int/bool/text) in the requirements table.

**EDIT**

NOTE: I already have 25 columns in the user table, so would it make any difference if I add 3 till 6 columns of demands? For the eye it will get a lot of information in 1 table.

Answer (score 2):

Use only one table to store this data, as i can not see if there is any complexity:

**Option 1:** (Use only one table)

```
|--------|-----------|----------------|-----------------|------------------------|
 user_id   user_name   minimal_salary   drivers_license           demands
|--------|-----------|----------------|-----------------|------------------------|
     1     John Doe         2000             true         These are my demands..
|--------|-----------|----------------|-----------------|------------------------|
```

**Option 2:** If the `parameters` are more for `user requirements` then you can make `two tables` one for `users` and other for `requirements` and you can have `user_id as foriegn id` in the other table. and then can `use a join` to retrieve the records.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no data that is common for other users, you can store it in one table.

If the demands for instance would be selected out of a list then I would suggest to store that possible list entries in a seperate table.

If you just don't need every field all the time, then select only the fields you need

don't do

```
select * from users where user_id = 123
```

do

```
select minimal_salary, drivers_license from users where user_id = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you provide the ability to let the user specify their own fields, I see no reason why you should break the information into a separate table.  All of those information fields apply to a single, distinct user.

Comment: The reason to put it in a seperate table, was that the user demands is an entity on it self. I only need to use this data when the user->get() function is called from the frontend. All the other times I need to use the user's information, I don't need to have the demands.

Comment: What sort of entity are the demands?  Above it looks like it is being represented as a simple string.

Comment: If you divide the responsibilities, you will have user, with his information, the user's demands, for example the user's updates, etc.
But maybe I am thinking to difficult now..